# how i can convert String to array String with condition

Tags: java-7

String t_liv="[http://X.X.X.X.X/trac/livraisons_t24/ticket/38068 38068]-[http://X.X.X.X.X/trac/livraisons_t24/ticket/38168 38168]-[http://X.X.X.X.X/trac/livraisons_t24/ticket/39312 39312]"

any solution to convert this String to array String with this format
[38068,38168,39312]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

split() will split a string into a string array depending on its parameter which is a regex that will act as your condition.

Comment: What regex will be needed? And will be be enough to just use the `split()` method?

Answer (score 0):

this my solution :

String t_liv="[http://X.X.X.X.X/trac/livraisons_t24/ticket/38068 38068]-[http://X.X.X.X.X/trac/livraisons_t24/ticket/38168 38168]-[http://X.X.X.X.X/trac/livraisons_t24/ticket/39312 39312]"

```
 public ArrayList<String> getAllIds(String t_liv) {
     ArrayList<String> arrayids = new ArrayList<String>();
     if(t_liv!=null)
     {
     String[] ids=t_liv.split("-");
     for(String p: ids)
        {
            
        String resultp= p.substring(p.length()-6);
            String resultfinal=resultp.substring(0,5);
            System.out.println(resultfinal);
            arrayids.add(resultfinal);
        }
    }
return  arrayids;
    }
```